# Enclosing a variable in brackets in Go

Tags: go

I am battling to understand what the `(*s)` does and I would appreciate an explanation.

```
// pop pops the stack. It will panic if s is empty.
func (s *nodeStack) pop() *Node {
    i := len(*s)
    n := (*s)[i-1]
    *s = (*s)[:i-1]
    return n
}
```

Comment: It dereferences the pointer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`s` is a pointer.  `*s` is the thing it points to.  The parentheses are to make clear -- both to the parser in the compiler, and to the human reader -- which one is being specified for array-style indexing.  That is, it's to disambiguate between:

```
(*s)[i-1]
```

and

```
*(s[i-1])
```